# Convert contents of DataGridView to List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, datagridview

What is the best way to grab the contents of a DataGridView and place those values into a list in C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
        List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            MyItem item = new MyItem();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
            { 
                ...build out MyItem....based on DataGridViewCell.OwningColumn and DataGridViewCell.Value  
            }

            items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: If within the foreach statement I wanted to access the value of the first element in the row how would I accomplish this?

Comment: The second foreach would contain your cell data...you move row by row...while extracting the data out of each cell within that row. Then make use of the DataGridViewCell.OwningColumn if you need to match things up otherwise it is linear and you can simply use DataGridViewCell.Value to extract the value of each cell as you move in a horizontal fashion across the data

Answer (score 11):

If you bind your list using DataSource, you can convert back by with:

```
List<Class> myClass = DataGridView.DataSource as List<Class>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Or a linq way

```
var list = (from row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
           from cell in row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
           select new 
           {
             //project into your new class from the row and cell vars.
           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var Result = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(
            r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray()).ToList();
```

or to get a string dictionary of the values

```
var Result = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(
            r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().ToDictionary(c => dataGridView1.Columns[c.OwningColumn].HeaderText, c => (c.Value ?? "").ToString()
                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable.OfType<TResult>` extension method can be your best friend here. Here is how I would have done it through a LINQ query:

```
List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList<DataGridViewRow>().ForEach(
                row =>
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        //I've assumed imaginary properties ColName and ColValue in MyItem class
                        items.Add(new MyItem { ColName = cell.OwningColumn.Name, ColValue = cell.Value });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

VB:

```vb
Dim lst As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = Me.MasterDataGridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).AsEnumerable.ToList
```

C#:

```cs
List<DataGridViewRow> lst = this.MasterDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>.AsEnumerable.ToList;
```