# How do I create a List<> from all the data in my DataGridView ?

Tags: c#, list, datagrid

I would like to create a List<> from all the data in my DataGridView. Do I need to create/structure a custom List class first? Or is there a way to systematically create (structure) the List<> from the DataGridView?

Thanks.

**Edit: Currently I have the following, but it does not do what I need.**

```
public class MigratedDataItems
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string MediaSize { get; set; }
        public int NumItems { get; set; }
        public int HandlingCost { get; set; }
        public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }


var migDataList = new List<VariablesClass.MigratedDataItems>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            migDataList.Add(new VariablesClass.MigratedDataItems 
            {
                Name = dgRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                DataType = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                MediaSize = dgRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                NumItems = int.Parse(dgRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()),
                HandlingCost = int.Parse(dgRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
                UnitPrice = int.Parse(dgRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString()),
                Total = int.Parse(dgRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString())
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281101/convert-contents-of-datagridview-to-list-in-c-sharp)

Google is your friend mate.

```
 List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            MyItem item = new MyItem();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
            { 
                ...build out MyItem....based on DataGridViewCell.OwningColumn and DataGridViewCell.Value  
            }

            items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your list using DataSource, you can convert back by,

```
List<Class> myClass= DataGridView.Datasource as List<Class> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above has helped me. I have the following code which adds all of my DataGridView values into a custom List<>.

```
class MigratedDataItems
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string MediaSize { get; set; }
        public int NumItems { get; set; }
        public int HandlingCost { get; set; }
        public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

public List<MigratedDataItems> QuoteList()                    
    {
        List<MigratedDataItems> migDataList = new List<MigratedDataItems>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            MigratedDataItems item = new MigratedDataItems();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dgRow.Cells)
            {
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 0) { item.Name = dc.Value.ToString(); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 1) { item.DataType = dc.Value.ToString(); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 2) { item.MediaSize = dc.Value.ToString(); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 3) { item.NumItems = int.Parse(dc.Value.ToString()); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 4) { item.HandlingCost = int.Parse(dc.Value.ToString()); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 5) { item.UnitPrice = int.Parse(dc.Value.ToString()); }
                if (dc.OwningColumn.Index == 6) { item.Total = int.Parse(dc.Value.ToString()); }
            }
            migDataList.Add(item);
        }
        return migDataList;
     }
```