# Save data in local variable using by silverlight(wcf+linq) connection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, silverlight, ado.net

Few days ago start programing in `SilverLight` and have a bit of a problem with saving data in local a variable from database by using `wcf`&`linq`. The connection and data result are working.

```
public void load(){
    ServiceReference.ServiceClient serv=new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();
    serv.GetAssetListCompleted+=new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetAssetListCompletedArgs>(serv_GetAssetListCompleted);
    serv.GetAssetListAsync();
}

void serv_GetAssetList(object sender, ServiceReference.GetAssetListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    datagrid1.ItemsSource=e.Result;
}
```

This code is working and my `datagrid1` is filling up with `element.(AutoGenerateColumns="True")` in Xaml-code. But I want to save this datagrid into a list or something else. Because I want to use these information like local variable.

Tried so many code like:

```
void serv_GetAssetList(object sender, ServiceReference.GetAssetListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var result_list=e.Result.toList();
}
```

Or

```
void serv_GetAssetList(object sender, ServiceReference.GetAssetListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] temp=new string[e.Result.Count];
    for (int i=0;i<e.Result.Count;i++)
    temp[i]=e.Result[i].Id;
}
```

But none work. All of them show an empty variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    void serv_GetAssetList(object sender, ServiceReference.GetAssetListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

   MessageBox.show(e.result.count);


    }
```

Comment: I have to declare out of these code a global variable but cant set that value to this.

Comment: your have global variable e1.result then why store in global variable

Comment: This code doesn't work tried to save a simple Column and still have empty array.

Comment: The MessegeBox.Show(e.result.count) is showing the rows number and if i try to loading its in a datagrid thats working too.
Just cant save in a local variable,list,or anything else.

Comment: output of this... otal no of rows

Comment: Or if u have some ideas how to "save" data elements from datagrid into a list that is same good. Because if its work i can easy hide the datagrid or send to beground where it is not visible

Comment: follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281101/convert-contents-of-datagridview-to-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: Try to used that link but that is only work in WPF project and in silverlight content only DataGrid and not datagridview

Comment: try this List<Employee> emp  = DataGridView.datasource as ( List<Employee> );

Comment: Its a silverlight application and dosent exist datagridview here only datagrid and that no have datasource method its have only itemsSource

Comment: replace datasource to item source

Comment: List<Person> people = dataGrid.ItemsSource as List<Person>

Comment: When i tried this code i have no error message and i have an empty list.

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
List<dolgozo> prob=datagridterulet.ItemsSource as List<dolgozo>;
MessageBox.Show(prob[0].neve);>}

And already tryed with 
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
List<WebService1.userinformation> prob=datagridterulet.ItemsSource as List<WebService1.userinformation>;
MessageBox.Show(prob[0].neve);}

Comment: cant easy copy here because coding other comp not here and sorry for writing style

Comment: in webservice i have userinformation datatable format because its loaded with ado.net and can use it  the LinQ code a simple Select * where its working i really dont know how can i fix it

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
this show with try block

Comment: The code foreach(var el in e.Result.ToList()) is working