# Convert GridView to List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi and thanks in advance. I'm having a problem implementing a suggestion that I found here: [Convert contents of DataGridView to List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281101/convert-contents-of-datagridview-to-list-in-c-sharp)

I am grabbing a GridView from a Master page and I need to add a row to the table then rebind it. I am accessing the GridView via a public property on the Master page which is being returned with data. So basically I have done this:

```
var gsr = master.GridSearchResults;
gsr (gsr != null)
{
   var so = new List<MyProperties>();
   so = gsr .Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray()).ToList<MyProperties>();
   so.Add(new MyProperties()
   {
      Id = id,
      Date = date,
      Building = buildingName,
      Street = streetName
   }
   gsr.DataSource = so;
   gsr.DataBind();
}
```

But I'm receiving an error that it cannot convert an instance argument type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'object[]'> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'MyProperties'>. I thought the problem was the call to the array but if I remove it then I just get a variation of the same error.

Comment: Have you tried .AsEnumerable<MyProperties>() instead of .ToList<MyProperties>() ?

Comment: It still shows the same error, but let me make a correction to my example because part of the error is missing now.

Comment: Have you tried .Cast<MyProperties>?

Comment: A GridView is different to a DataGridView. They are different objects. DataGridView is for Windows Forms is it not? Whilst GridView is for ASP.NET.

Comment: Ok, I understand they are different and the statement is not correct, so what is the correct way to select the rows from the GridView into the list?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue was that I shouldn't have been getting the gridview in the first place but getting the the Gridview's source which was in session. So I solved it like this:

```
        var master = (Tab)Master;
        master.GridSearchResults.DataSource = null;
        var sessions = new Sessions();
        sessions.SlideOutSource.Add(new MyProperties {
                                       Id = Id,
                                       StartDate = hidStartDate.Value,
                                       Installation = txtInstall.Text,
                                       Command = txtCommand.Text  });

        master.GridSearchResults.DataSource = sessions.SlideOutSource;
        master.GridSearchResults.DataBind();
```